# Jump to other void

Tags: java, void

I got this code:

```
public void main(){

}

public void first(){
    System.out.println("first void");
}

public void second(){
    System.out.println("second void");
}

public void third(){
    System.out.println("third void");
}
```

Now I want to add a code to the main void that would skip to the third one for example. That means, that the console output will be:

> third void

Comment: call your method in your main like so: `third();`

Comment: lol it was just that easy.. but thank you alot! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @TomLenc You should _really_ work through some basic java tutorials first!

Comment: I know stuff like so:
`myclass mc = new myclass();
mc.firstvoid();`

but I never realized I could do it in local class..
And I already watched basics tutorials

Comment: @TomLenc: It's `MyClass mc = new MyClass()` instead ;)

Comment: @Parth even though I do agree with camelcasing, it doesn't mean that he's wrong for writing it like that. As for Tom, I suggest you to follow isnot2bad's advice and watch some tutorials. If you will continue to ask basic questions like this you might find your account suspended sooner or later. Good luck with the programming

Comment: @Parth not so much 'instead' (since that snippet would compile) but more accepted via standard CamelCase conventions :)

Comment: @Bas and TomLenc I was just kidding guys. Didn't you see `;` at the end. Don't take it seriously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will produce the desired output:

```
public void main(){
  third();
}

public void first(){
    System.out.println("first void");
}

public void second(){
    System.out.println("second void");
}

public void third(){
    System.out.println("third void");
}
```

Please note that it does not "skip" the `first` and `second` function, but simply does not call them. I'm not sure whether this makes a difference for you or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you execute your code from your main method call it like

```
public void main(){
    third();
}
```